# Finding duplicated elements in 2 arrays without using nested loop

Tags: c++

I want a program to find duplicated elements in 2 arrays without using 2 nested loop.
I've tried 2 for loop but it takes too much time.

Here what I have done:

```
for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
        if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]){
            // function
        } else if(arr1[i] != arr2[j]) {
            // another function
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the readily availble function "set_intersection", explained here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection

Comment: @Sepehr How about 2 separate for loops?

Comment: I don't know it will takes less time or not? @AshokArora

Comment: Your solution: O(n*n). With "set_intersection". 2 times ````std::sort```` with O(nlog(n))  + O(n) for the intersection

Comment: @Sepehr 2 nested for loop take O(n*n) wheres 2 separate for loop will take O(n) + O(n) which is still O(n), so it will be faster than your approach

Answer (score 3):

Build a hashset from elements from array1, then iterate over array2 to find duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

This solution will show you 3 methods and measure the time that they need.

1. Your approach, using a nested loop
2. Using `std::set_intersection`
3. Using `std::unordered_set`

There are of course more possible solutions.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>

constexpr size_t ArraySize1 = 100000u;
constexpr size_t ArraySize2 = 150000u;

int main() {

    int arr1[ArraySize1], arr2[ArraySize2];

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Create some random numbers and fill both arrays with it
    std::random_device rd;  
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); 
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(1, 2000000000);

    for (int& i : arr1) i = distrib(gen);
    for (int& i : arr2) i = distrib(gen);

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Test algorithms

    // 1. Nested loops
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    // ---
    for (size_t k = 0; k < ArraySize1; ++k)
        for (size_t i = 0; i < ArraySize2; ++i)
            if (arr1[k] == arr2[i])
                std::cout << arr1[k] << '\n';
    // ---

    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
    std::cout << "Time with nested loops: " << elapsed.count() << " ms\n\n";

    // 2. Set intersection
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    // ---
    std::sort(std::begin(arr1), std::end(arr1));
    std::sort(std::begin(arr2), std::end(arr2));
    std::set_intersection(std::begin(arr1), std::end(arr1), std::begin(arr2), std::end(arr2), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
    // ---

    elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
    std::cout << "Time with set_intersection: " << elapsed.count() << " ms\n\n";

    // 3. std::unordred_set
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::unordered_set<int> setArray1(std::begin(arr1),std::end(arr1));
    for (const int i : arr2) {
        if (setArray1.count(i)) {
            std::cout << i << '\n';
        }
    }

    elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
    std::cout << "Time with unordered set: " << elapsed.count() << " ms\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- using **bool visited** array for array1, then check duplicates in
  array2 [it depends on array elements limitation]
- using **map or set** C++ STL
- using **Trie data structure** (advanced technique)